# PowerMockito throwing ClassNotPreparedException even with @PrepareForTest using Scala Test

Tags: scala, powermock, scalatest, powermockito

I have the following test...

```
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
...
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(classOf[JUnitRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[AuditLog]))
class ConnectorAPITest extends path.FreeSpec with ShouldMatchers {
  "Mocked Tests" - {
      println("This got called in the mocked tests.")
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(classOf[AuditLog]);
      ...
  }
}
```

But when I run I get...

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: The class com.paxata.services.log.AuditLog not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
In case if you don't use this annotation, add the annotation on class or  method level. 
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
The class com.paxata.services.log.AuditLog not prepared for test.
To prepare this class, add class to the '@PrepareForTest' annotation.
```

Which doesn't make sense given the annotation is already there? Is it an idiosyncrasy of Scala test?

Comment: What happens if you try to use the full classpath in the annotation?

Comment: You can try `@PrepareForTest({AuditLog.class})` instead of that.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem using FunSuite. It works when I turned to JUnit.

```
@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[SomeStaticClass]))
class MyTestClass {

  @Before
  def setUp {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(classOf[SomeStaticClass])
    Mockito.when(SomeStaticClass.getSomeObject(1)).thenReturn(new SomeObject(1))
  }

@Test
def someTestMethod {
}
```

etc...

Comment: But it would be great to know how to make it work with ScalaTest

Comment: I tried the same thing but scala test wouldn't find the tests.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is not the issue for me, I'm running tests with junit runner in IntelliJ Idea.